# Google Chrome Extension for inserting code/text snippets

Tags: google-chrome, software-rec, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

Is anyone aware of a Google Extension that enables one to insert text into the currently focussed (text) area after some predefined keyboard short cuts?

For example, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, the following text is inserted:

```
<code></code>
```

Of course, the keyboard short cuts, and the text that is to be inserted, are configurable.

I've searched the [Chrome Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/?hl=en) site, but could't find anything.

If you're aware of some other browser besides Google Chrome that has this through some extension/add-on, I'd also appreciate that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YakShave](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cdkefpgghindmmclchkbcdgikbpnbiaj) might be what you are looking for. It allows you to program your own shortcuts, or open your favorite text editor to work with web forms (Emacs or Vim, anyone?)

Now if configuring it is too much work for you, there are other extensions that can expand abbreviatons ([Just one that I found](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/iinhokidgfoomcighckbjmlcndbjmomp)). You could set one up to expand `<c>` into `<code></code>`, for example.

Using a browser or addon that is modeled after Emacs or Vim (Conkeror, Vimperator, etc.) is another extremely powerful option. But learning them just in order to use a few shortcuts is probably overkill.

Comment: YakShave looks impressive, but a bit too much for what I want. Popchrom however is exactly what I needed. Unfortunately, the cursor can't be positioned somewhere in the substituted text, but hey, beggars can't be choosers! :) I'll see if I hack this in myself. Many thanks!

Comment: It seems I can't award the bounty for another 23 hours. Will do so in due time. Thanks again.